# UnicodeDecodeError when using QFileDialog getOpenFileName()

Tags: python, unicode, error-handling, pyqt4

The code is like 
*dlg = PyQt4.QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
   self.filename = dlg.getOpenFileName()*

When the Dialog pops up, I click on a file having Chinese characters in its path. Then I get the UnicodeDecodeError.

I tried the toUtf8() function, but still get nowhere.

Unicode thing is always so difficult to understand. Anybody helps me out of this?

Answer (score 2):

The UnicodeDecodeError thing probably happens *after* the code you posted. Anyway, try

```
self.filename = PyQt4.QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName().decode('utf-8')
```

By the way, getOpenFilename() is a static method of QFileDialog, which means you don't have to create an instance to call it.

Comment: When I try decode('utf-8'), it says 'QString' has no attribute 'decode'. So I use str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()).decode('utf-8'), and the UnicodeDecodeError remains.

Comment: Hmm, you can try unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()) then.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark that appears next to it.  That way people will see that you are willing to reward those who help you.